# C# How to split text, but without removing delimiter?

Tags: c#, symbols

I wanna split text by mathematical symbols [(),-,+,/,*,^].
For eg. "(3*21)+4/2" should make array {"(","3","*","21",")","+","4","/","2"}

I was trying do that by regex.split but brackets are problematic.

Comment: you should include what you have tried ...

Comment: Why adopt so complex way; it seems all of your strings are of a character each, why not read a character a time and store in separate string array! But, I feel this is a XY-problem!

Comment: Just sayin': If you are searching for expression manipulation and stuff maybe you could use NCalc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what problem you encountered with Regex.Split, but it seems quite simple. All you have to do is escape the character that have special meaning in regex. Like so:

```
string input = "(3*21+[3-5])+4/2";
string pattern = @"(\()|(\))|(\d+)|(\*)|(\+)|(-)|(/)|(\[)|(\])";

var result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
var result2 = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Edit: updated pattern, '-' and '/' don't have to be escaped.

Afterwards you got 2 options: first one is using `Split`, it will make string array, but in between every match will be empty string. That's why I think you should go for `Matches` and transforming it to array of string is simple afterwards.

```
string[] stringResult = (from Match match in result select match.Value).ToArray();

stringResult
{string[15]}
    [0]: "("
    [1]: "3"
    [2]: "*"
    [3]: "21"
    [4]: "+"
    [5]: "["
    [6]: "3"
    [7]: "-"
    [8]: "5"
    [9]: "]"
    [10]: ")"
    [11]: "+"
    [12]: "4"
    [13]: "/"
    [14]: "2"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run through source string, adding to array cell if current value is a number, or moving to next array cell if not ([,*,-, etc...).

Answer (score -1):

**I really think something like this will come in handy..

First, use getline and take all the input or if u already have a string, store it.**

```
 string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then create an array of length string.length...

```
string[] arr = new string[input.Length]; 
//Make sure ur input doesnt have spaces
```

Then store each value of the array to the value of string!! 
Like this

```
str[0]=arr[0];
```

This should work properly do this for all the
 characters or could use a for loop..

```
for(int i=0;i<input.Length;i++){
str[i]=arr[i];
 }
```

That's it ...

Comment: But then the "21" will be stored as "2" and "1" - I don't think that is wanted